# Loop through array every time a function is called - cycling colours in canvas 2d Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I'm trying to cycle through items in an array every time a function is called in a parent function.

```
const wildColours = ["green", "blue", "orange", "red", "purple", "yellow", "white"]

function drawGame() { // this is drawing elements on the canvas every 100 milliseconds.  
   nCanvasDrawElements();
   drawWildCard();
   setTimeout(drawGame, 100);
};

function drawWildCard() {
  for (i = 0; i < wildColours.length; i++) {
    let wildCycle = wildColours[i];    
    context.fillStyle = wildCycle;
    context.fillRect(wildCardX, wildCardY, tileSize, tileSize);
    console.log(wildCycle);
  }
};

drawGame();
```

It's returning all items in the array each time drawWildCard() is called in drawGame().

I'd like to continuously(cycle) through the colours in the wildColours array, each time I draw the drawWildCard() function in drawGame()

So that the WildCard cycles through the array of colours every 100 milliseconds with all the other game elements.

The project is [here](https://codepen.io/kieren-wuest/pen/VwxYrgb) and I am just learning to code. If anyone can explain the answer I would really appreciate it.

Comment: What is the current behavior of this function?

Comment: it draws a fillRect (rectangle) with a fillStyle of a specific colour on a 2d html canvas with other elements in the game.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to keep track of the last chosen color *outside* of `drawWildCard`. In every `drawGame` loop, you can then change the color *once*.

To make sure you cycle through each color, you have to make sure you start from the first color once you reach the end of the array.

You can do so by incrementing an index every time and taking the [remainder](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Remainder?retiredLocale=de) of the index divided by the total number of colors.

```js
nextIndex = (previousIndex + 1) % totalNrOfcolors;
```

```js
const context = document.querySelector("canvas").getContext("2d");
const wildCardX = 0, wildCardY = 0, tileSize = 200;

let wildIndex = 0;
const wildColours = ["green", "blue", "orange", "red", "purple", "yellow", "white"]

function drawGame() { // this is drawing elements on the canvas every 100 milliseconds.  
   drawWildCard();
   setTimeout(drawGame, 100);
};

function drawWildCard() {
  const wildCycle = wildColours[wildIndex];    
  context.fillStyle = wildCycle;
  context.fillRect(wildCardX, wildCardY, tileSize, tileSize);

  wildIndex = (wildIndex + 1) % wildColours.length;
  
};

drawGame();
```

```html
<canvas width="200" height="200"></canvas>
```

Comment: That is awesome, I love how you can run the answer simply there

Comment: Thank you for your help and explaining the solution.

Comment: How would I adjust this so that is cycles through the array only once?

Comment: If you don't want it to go back to the start, you could replace the last line of `drawWildCard` with: `if (wildIndex < wildColours.length - 1) wildIndex += 1;`

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work, but I'm not exactly sure how ... what I used works ... exactly .

Some form of index remainder array method thing-a-majig

```
array[index++ % array.length]
```

that I found in this solution [Javascript: How to loop through every array's item every second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46354221/javascript-how-to-loop-through-every-arrays-item-every-second)

The working code is:

```js
const context = document.querySelector("canvas").getContext("2d");
const wildCardX = 0, wildCardY = 0, tileSize = 200;

const wildColours = ["green", "blue", "orange", "red", "purple", "yellow", "white"]
let index = 0;

function drawGame() { // this is drawing elements on the canvas every 100 milliseconds.  
   drawWildCard();
   setTimeout(drawGame, 100);
};

function drawWildCard() {
    context.fillStyle = wildColours[index++ % wildColours.length];
    context.fillRect(wildCardX, wildCardY, tileSize, tileSize);
};

drawGame();
```

```html
<canvas width="200" height="200"></canvas>
```

Thanks user3297291 for explaining